# React recursively provide data to components

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a framework where components can be nested in one another without directly nesting them. Instead I want to use certain placeholder components that will dynamically find out which component it should render in its place. For example I have three components:

```js
function Component1() {
    return <div>Component 1<RoutingSlot/></div>
}

function Component2() {
    return <div>Component 2<RoutingSlot/></div>
}

function Component3() {
    return <div>Component 3</div>
}
```

I also have a list with the components that should be rendered in their correct order, e.g. `[ Component1, Component2, Component3 ]`. The component `RoutingSlot` will then be substituted with the next component in the list. Meaning, the resulting component tree would look like this:

```js
<Component1>
    Component1
    <Component2>
        Component2
        <Component3>
            Component2
        </Component3>
    </Component2>
</Component1>
```

Since these component do not need to be direct descendants (and also for convenience purposes) I can not to pass the component list through regular component props. Instead, I tried using a context. This works perfectly fine for passing the list, but my issue lies in finding out at which nesting level I am currently at (i.e. which element in the list needs to be accessed).

This (kinda) works by nesting the same context provider again and again (for each `<RoutingSlot/>`, to set the new index in the component list), but this is misuse of the contexts and react warns/complains when I do so.

My next attempt was to pass down a `pop()` function through the context, which would return the next component in the list each time it was called (i.e. the first call would give the component at index zero, the second call at index one and so on). This did not work because I needed to modify the state (i was storing the current index) during render which also breaks React.

Essentially, what I am looking for is the ability to attach certain metadata (an index in this case) to certain components and then, from a child component, walk the component tree upwards until I find closest parent with attached metadata. Is there a way to implement this?